# What does it mean for a classification model to expect more features

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I am trying to predict some test data using MLPClassifier but getting this error:

ValueError: X has 17 features, but MLPClassifier is expecting 18 features as input. What could this mean??

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A machine learning model is essentially a statistical formula that accepts certain number of inputs and gives a numerical output. In your case, there should be 18 input values, not 17.
Let's assume that you are using logistic regression. In this case, your model is as follows:

yp = 1 / (1 + e^-(a1*x1 + a2*x1 ... a18*x18))

If you don't provide a18, the model has now way of predicting it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I appreciate. Would to like to ask if you don't mind, how does one know the number of input features??? Is there a function?

Comment: @CalebChege Whoever builds the model decides the number of features. In most ML packages, you input X_train data. The number of features in this X_train is the number of features expected as input.